# jQuery: wrapInner with href of parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have TR which have href added (invalid HTML, I know); and I would like to get the content inside the TDs to get the href of the TR.

Sounds pretty simple but I've been unable to get it done. I've tried the following code:

```
$("table td").wrapInner("<a href='" + $(this).parent().data("href") + "'></a>");
```

However it's returning undefined.

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yy3w7fqz/

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parent (`<tr>`) does not have `data-href` attribute, in our case it just `attribute` and you can get it use method [.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). Also in our case you should specify `callback function` (like in example) and this `callback` will be called once for every matched element, and `$(this)` will be refer to `<td>`

```
$("table td").wrapInner(function () {
    return "<a href='" + $(this).parent().attr("href") + "' target='_blank'></a>"
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yy3w7fqz/1/)

**Update**

```
$("table td").wrapInner(function () {
    if ($(this).parent().attr("href")) {
        return "<a href='" + $(this).parent().attr("href") + "' target='_blank'></a>"
    }
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yy3w7fqz/3/)

Comment: My bad, yes I meant limiting it to those TR with the href attribute. I tried using hasAttr but it's not working: http://jsfiddle.net/yy3w7fqz/2/